# estoy intentando determinar cual fecha es menor o mayor en angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

lo que trato es devolver los campos con la fecha de mi arreglo que sean mayores o menores que la que tengo en mi selector... el campo dateFromformattedString, dateToformattedString es una fecha del selector por ejemplo
Tengo dos fechas en el tipo de datos de cadena y necesito saber cuál es menor o mayor, estoy intentado simplemente asi dateFromformattedString >= res.CreationTime alguna otra forma facil y rapida:

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(
        (res) => {
          this.responses = res;
          this.responsesTotalCant = res.length;

          var resultados2 = res.filter( (res) => {
            
            console.log('segundo resultado: ',res.CreationTime,  dateToformattedString);

            return dateFromformattedString >= res.CreationTime
              && dateToformattedString <= res.CreationTime 
              && res.AgencyName === agencyName.trim() 
              && res.ResponseType === responseType.trim() ;
           
          });

          if(this.responsesTotalCant == 0){
            console.log('nohayresultados');
          }else {
            this.responses = resultados2;
          }
          this.responsesTotalCant = resultados2.length;
          console.log(resultados2);
          });
      
    } else {
      console.log('todos los campos son obligatorios');
    } 
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puedes editar y añadir la respuesta completa que recibes del servicio? Puedes indicar también cuál sería el resultado esperado?

Comment: Claro, ya adjunto el servicio y lo que recibo

Answer (score 0):

Encontre esta forma para solucionar lo que esperaba, como respuesta era  los items que se obtienen por medio del servicio los cuales contengan lo que es igual a res.AgencyName === agencyName.trim() && res.ResponseType === responseType.trim()  y agregue return moment(res.CreationTime) > moment(dateFromformattedString)
&& moment(res.CreationTime) < moment(dateToformattedString)
&& res.AgencyName === agencyName.trim()
&& res.ResponseType != null;      y me funciono, esperaba los items indicando un rango de fecha pero no habia trabajado anteriormente con fechas y comparandolas me apoye de moment.js para resolverlo y manejar las fechas junto con la libreria